# Is a darlington constructed with 2 BJTs fully equivalent to an integrated one?

Tags: bjt, darlington

Is a darlington constructed with 2 BJTs fully equivalent to an integrated one? The reason I'm asking is that there are obvious differences, like the collectors which are separated, and also the emitter of one BJT and the base of the other.

Answer (score 6):

Not per se, since integrated Darlingtons usually have resistors that desaturate the transistors when turned off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1w7kQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>